# Is it possible to revert a RAID 1 operation?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid

I accidentaly turned a full disk into an exact replicate of another, now I'm struggling to find a way to restore my lost files. Is there any ?

Comment: So you had disk A and disk B, which were independent. Then you turned disk B into a RAID 1 array with disk A as the master. Now you want to recover the data that was on disk B. Correct? (If so, the answer is: reach for your most recent backup.)

Comment: Related/Duplicate: [Recover data from NTFS disk after RAID1 mirror operation](http://superuser.com/questions/316650/recover-data-from-ntfs-disk-after-raid1-mirror-operation)

Comment: Recent backup ? like BIOS back up ?

Comment: Unfortunately when you created the RAID 1 array all the information from the source HDD was written to the one you want to recover. This overwrote the old data. If the HDD is not completely full you might be able to recover a part of the data using data recovery software.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you're out of luck.  A RAID 1 operation is basically a format and full drive write operation, which is about as destructive as you can get, other than deliberately zeroing all sectors.

Comment: the odd thing is that it happened in a wink, yet I thought formatting and copying a whole 500Gb drive takes time

Comment: A partition write takes a second to complete.  The rest of the mirroring operation may not have been the full 80gb, but neither is it sequential, so it will be writing all over the place depending on the mirroring algorithm.